# Consolidated Answer: How to extract a SF report using Python

Tags: rest-api, api, reporting, python, reports-api

I've been searching around the site for the past week or two and there seem to be a lot of opinions and ideas on how to download a report into a DataFrame from SF using Python (`simple-salesforce` & `salesforce-reporting`) but none provide a proper and actionable answer.

So for my self and everyone who will need this in the future I'd love to know if theres a concrete answer to the question: **can you download a report from salesforce using python?**

If not, does anyone have a proper recommendation of how to proceed using SOQL?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [simple\_salesforce Run Report](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/253462/simple-salesforce-run-report)

Comment: _Downloading_ a report (i.e., in "XLS" or CSV format) and _running_ a report (through the Analytics API, with response body in JSON) are very different. Could you [edit] to clarify what you are trying to do and where the specific problem is located?

Comment: @identigral i found that before but it's not immediately obvious how to parse out the data contained in the datacells

Comment: @DavidReed Updated! your answer [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/253464/90627) is brilliant but i'm not sure (and im sure a lot of other people are unsure as well) as to how to parse the incoming data from those datacells

Comment: @Gorlomi What have you tried? Where are you stuck? The Salesforce portion of this problem is covered in David's answer, here's another example  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57575852/how-to-download-a-report-as-a-csv-directly-from-salesforce-lightning . The rest is just writing code in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found the answer in a website I can't find again but luckily I saved the code locally.

For anyone **just trying to download a report into a DataFrame** this is how you do it (I added some notes and links for clarifications):

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import requests
from io import StringIO
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce

# Input Salesforce credentials:
sf = Salesforce(
    username='johndoe@mail.com', 
    password='<password>', 
    security_token='<security_token>') # See below for help with finding token 

# Basic report URL structure:
orgParams = 'https://<INSERT_YOUR_COMPANY_NAME_HERE>.my.salesforce.com/' # you can see this in your Salesforce URL
exportParams = '?isdtp=p1&export=1&enc=UTF-8&xf=csv'

# Downloading the report:
reportId = 'reportId' # You find this in the URL of the report in question between "Report/" and "/view"
reportUrl = orgParams + reportId + exportParams
reportReq = requests.get(reportUrl, headers=sf.headers, cookies={'sid': sf.session_id})
reportData = reportReq.content.decode('utf-8')
reportDf = pd.read_csv(StringIO(reportData))
```

You can get your token by following the instructions at the bottom of [this page](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=user_security_token.htm&type=5)